# How can I change the static property field's value in a property decorator in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I'd like to give the static properties some initial values based on certain calculation if those properties have been decorated so I made such code:

```
function deco(display?: string) {
  // It looks like `any` could work here instead of `T` but I don't want to use `any`
  return function <T> (target: T, key: string) {
    /*
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{}'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{}'.ts(7053)
    */
    if (typeof target[key] !== 'number') {
      target[key] = 0
    }
  }
}

class A {
    @deco('foo')
    static foo : number

    @deco('bar')
    static bar : number
}
```

How could I make it work?

Comment: Your problem does not end there, because `@deco('foo')` and `@deco('bar')` have error. and it's because of we can't extend `A` from `{ [k: string]: number }`. So you should first solve this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you don't want to use `any`, you could try something like this for the factory (inner) function, using additional method type parameters and a type [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types):

```js
return function <T, K extends keyof T> (target: T, key: K) {
  if (typeof target[key] !== 'number') {
    target[key] = 0 as T[K] & number;
  }
}
```

The issue with this code is that it assumes `@deco` will only be used on properties of `number` type, and may have unexpected behavior otherwise. For instance, if you use this decorator on a property of type `string`, it will still set its value to `0`. This is acceptable because TypeScript is just a superset of JavaScript - and so is perfectly valid JavaScript - and we force the setting of `target[key]` to be the intersection type of `T[K]` (i.e. the TypeScript-defined type of `target[key]`; to allow setting `target[key]` to the value) and `number` (to allow the number `0` to be assigned). It skirts around type safety.

Ideally, you would be setting initial values directly at their declaration rather than relying on a decorator to populate them.

Comment: What does this expression `T[K] & number` mean?

Comment: @jayatubi `T[K] & number` is the intersection of `T[K]` and `number` types.

Comment: Great. The `T[K] & number` resolve my problem. I never see a documentation about such usage before. Could you please share a link about it?

Comment: @jayatubi Edited the answer with the documentation reference on intersections.